# lookahead assertions

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match a label within a valid domain name using a regular expression in Python:

```
DOMAIN_LABEL_RE = """
\A(
(?<![\d\-]) # cannot start with digit or hyphen, looking behind
([a-zA-Z\d\-]*?)
([a-zA-Z]+)# need at least 1 letter
([a-zA-Z\d\-]*?)
(?!\-) # cannot end with a hyphen, looking ahead
)\Z
"""
```

I'm trying to use a positive and negative assertion to avoid a hyphen at the beginning or end of the label.

But the string "-asdf" still matches:
    e.match(DOMAIN_LABEL_RE, "-asdf", re.VERBOSE).group()

I don't understand why it's still matching.

Thanks for any help.

M.

Comment: You have your aheads and behinds exchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\A` matches the start of the string and the following lookbehind matches if there is no hyphen before that position.

You are at the beginning of the string, of course there is no character before it!

Use a negative lookahead instead: `(?![\d\-])`.

Similar for the end of the string. You have to use a negative lookbehind instead `(?<!\-)`.

I think an equivalent expressions to your current one would be:

```
DOMAIN_LABEL_RE = """
(?i               # case insensitive
  \A(
    ([a-z])       # need at least 1 letter and cannot start with digit or hyphen
    ([a-z\d-]*?)
    (?<!-)        # cannot end with a hyphen
  )\Z
)
"""
```

**Note:** I did not check whether the expression is actually suited for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: While you're at it, replace the `(?<!-)` with `[a-z\d]`.  Lookahead and lookbehind need not apply for this job.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, I had this before but I had *not hyphen* in mind, so I though the negative lookbehind conveys the intention better. Of course  I could have just though *should only end with a letter or digit*... :D

Comment: @Alan, I'm not sure if replacing the (?<!-) with [a-z\d] would work.  This would disallow a label with only a single letter.

Comment: @user891441: Ah yes. The documentation also mentioned `re.I`, and that confused me ;) Fixed.